# How do I respond to an email that I have delayed answering?

Tags: email

I'm undertaking an engineering project, and coincidentally met an expert in the field at a school talk. After talking briefly, he took down my email and offered to help with a section on analysis.

He then sent me an email a couple of days later asking what he could do to help.

Now I really regret this, but I have now left replying to this email for over 5 weeks, and am unsure whether this is a completely lost cause.

There is no reason for me leaving it, other than initial laziness, then the inability to think how to reply after the first week or so; it is now just out of hand.

Needless to day I've learned my lesson, but what would be the best way to let him know I'd like his involvement, without coming across as rude, or implying that his help is only now needed?

Answer (score 13):

> Hi [name],
>
> I'm sorry it took so long for me to get back to you.  If you're still
>   interested I could still use help with .  If you'd like to discuss
>   my number is ....

If they're still interested they'll let you know.

Comment: Basically this but: 1) after 5 weeks OP is going to need to describe the moment they met and his project, especially given the context of the meeting, 2) I'd make the language less direct and replace help with feedback or so, 3) many engineers will prefer communicating over Skype over something like this so OP may want to give those details as well.

Comment: Also, in the future, you can send a short email saying that you'll have more time to collaborate at a certain date.